# Qlikview set analysis previous month

Tags: date, variables, qlikview

I'm working since a couple of weeks with Qlikview and have loaded SQL server data inclusing a Reportdate (tried both date and datetime types) which is allways an ultimo month date.

Now I've created an variable as follows:

```
vPreviousMonth = MonthEnd(AddMonths(GetFieldSelections(Reportdate),-1))
```

I've checked the results by selecting all the different dates. Conclusion allways the correct results. Selecting `2014-01-31` gives `2013-12-31`, `2014-03-31` gives `2014-02-28`, etc.

Now I want to use this variable in the set analysis option to aggregate all amounts in previous month. I've used the following expression:

```
sum( { $< Reportdate = {$(vPreviousMonth)}  > } Amount )
```

with no succes. I've also tried it with numeric dates, but also with no succes.
Is there someone who can help me with a workable solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your variable to a date, using `Date()`, as `MonthEnd()` returns a time stamp.

```
vPreviousMonth = Date(MonthEnd(AddMonths(GetFieldSelections(Reportdate),-1)))
```

I'm assuming that Reportdate is a date type

Answer (score 0):

You have selected a month and so Qlikview is selecting this month in the whole data set. This means all the data with `Reportdate = {$(vPreviousMonth)}` is not longer part of the data set and cannot be selected. If you try to select data of the previous month you have do set a flag while loading the data. 
Then you don't have to click on a Datefield to Show the previous month. 
The set Expression would look like `sum({<FlagPrevMonth = {1}>}Amount)`.

Good to know: With this solution you can only Report the last month. If you try to Report more month in the past you have to do more flags.And you cannot click on a month because then this month will be selected through the whole data set again.

Another not so recommended solution is to create the calendar separetly without a link to the rest of the data. Then you can create the variable like yours but referenced to a calendar field on which the selection schould be done.
example: 
`vLastDayPrevMonth = CAL.LAST_DAY_PREV`
`sum({<ReportDate = {'$(vLastDayPrevMonth)'}>}Amount)`
Then the selections should be done on the calendar fileds and you could make the Report dynamically.